# 405 not found error in delete mapping method of springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, microservices

Question Controller

```
    import com.jay.login.entitie.Mcq_Question;
    import com.jay.login.service.QuestionService;

    @RestController

    public class QuestionController {

        @Autowired

        QuestionService qs;

        private static final Logger l=  LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuestionController.class);

        @PostMapping("/Questions")
       
         Mcq_Question addQuestion(@RequestBody Mcq_Question q)
        { System.out.println(q);
          return    qs.addQuestion(q);
        
         }
    @PutMapping("/Questions")

    Mcq_Question updateQuestion(@RequestBody Mcq_Question q)
    {
        return qs.updateQuestion(q);
    }

    @GetMapping("/Questions/{question_id}")

    Mcq_Question getQuestion(@RequestParam(name="question_id") String id)
    {
        return qs.getQuestion(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }

    @GetMapping("/Questions")

    List<Mcq_Question> getQuestions()
    {
        
        return qs.getQuestions();
    }

    @RequestMapping(name="/Questions/{question_id}",method = RequestMethod.DELETE) 

    ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>  deleteQuestion(@RequestParam(name = "question_id",required =false) String id)
    {
        try {
            l.info(""+id);
    qs.deleteQuestion(Integer.parseInt(id));    
    l.debug(""+id);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            l.debug("jay  ijfiji"+e);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }   
          }
    }
```

ERROR is as:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-05-10T05:43:25.351+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:251)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:435)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:376)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:66)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1254)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1036)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\r\n",
    "message": "Request method 'DELETE' not supported",
    "path": "/Questions"
}
```

on client side I am using postman to hit api

method
Delete mapping

> http://localhost:8080/Questions?question_id=78

Comment: its telling you "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' not supported\r\n\tat 

PLease use @DeleteMapping instead

Comment: Thank you for replying but i have used delete mapping code

Comment: I have tried @DeleteMapping but it is giving still same error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping i found that problem is with my db i tried their manually deleting data but some constraints in table where not allowing to delete data